# Why is Linq.Sum() with decimals ambiguous between int and int?

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, overload-resolution

*short:*
I have a method `decimal GetAmount(IThing thing)`. Using `things.Sum(GetAmount)` results in a CS0121 error: call is ambiguous between `Sum(Func<T, int>)` and `Sum(Func<T, int?>)`. Why?

*longer:*

```
public interface IThing { }
public class Sample {
    public decimal GetAmount(IThing thing) { return 0; }
    public decimal Total(IThing[] things) { return things.Sum(GetAmount); }
}
```

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: `'Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   Func<TSource, int>)'` and
>   `'Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int?>)'`

I would somewhat understand if the compiler was confused between `decimal` and `decimal?` or if the compiler couldn't pick any of the many Sum overloads. But why/how did it limit itself to only `int` and `int?`

Btw, VS / R# 'helpfully' highlights passing `GetAmount` to `.Sum()` as an error and suggests passing an int returning method instead. The compiler doesn't flag this part as a second error. Changing `GetAmount` to `int GetAmount(IThing thing)` actually does 'solve' the compiler error.

ps. I'm not looking for a solution to the compiler error. I know I can turn GetAmount into `Func<IThing, decimal> GetAmount { get; }` or implement Total like `things.Sum(thing => GetAmount(thing))`. And as suggested by @IvanStoev, `things.Sum(new Func<IThing, decimal>(GetAmount))` works (for me) as well.

Comment: I suppose it´s because the compiler can´t ditinguish methods only because of their return-type. However I wonder why compiler even *needs* to distinguish, as there´s only one method. Good question though.

Comment: I don't know where the int came from, but I am [getting error with decimals](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZoCY2G)

Comment: @mybirthname This works as long as there is an unambigous method to infer which it *is* in the OPs case.

Comment: @HimBromBeere so  you gave him the answer when there is ambiguous method you can't do that. Why because the compiler is written that way. He can propose it as feature in the future.

Comment: @mybirthname No, the question is: *where* is that ambuigity? I see only one `GetAmount`-method expecting a `IThing` and returning a `decimal`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere okay wait for the guy which wrote the compiler to show and explain what is going on. Just to mention so I think is not an answer of the question.

Answer (score 5):

You just don't have overload of `.Sum()` where you can pass your method.

You right you can do it that way:

```
things.Sum(thing => GetAmount(thing))
```

`thing => GetAmount(thing)` - this part basically will create anonymouse function and `.Sum()` got overload for it.

One of the other ways to implement it (more obviouse way so you can understand what actually happends) is create func yourself:

```
public decimal Total(IThing[] things) 
{ 
   return things.Sum(new Func<IThing, decimal>(GetAmount)); 
}
```

Actually i get another compiler error with your code (I use VS 2015).

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0407  'decimal Sample.GetAmount(IThing)' has the wrong return
>   type

So I think you get that wired error only becouse precompiler analizer is not perfect.

I did a bit more research and try to compile your code without precompiler from command prompt like this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe
>   /out:Program.exe Program.cs

And now compiler return right error:

> Program.cs(13,56): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the
>   following methods or properties:
>   `'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum<Lambda.IThing>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Lambda.IThing>, System.Func<Lambda.IThing,decimal>)'` and
>   `'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum<Lambda.IThing>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Lambda.IThing>, System.Func<Lambda.IThing,decimal?>)'`

As you see now we got right error with `decimal` type. So wierd compiler error that we get located somewhere in precompiler sources.

Comment: Hmm, when I use `return things.Sum(new Func<IThing, decimal>(GetAmount));` I don't get any compiler error. What's going on here? I'm using VS2015.

Comment: @IvanStoev i get this compiler error with OP code - `public decimal Total(IThing[] things) { return things.Sum(GetAmount); }`

Comment: I see. Still strange because I get the same error as OP :)

Comment: @IvanStoev hm... I created new console application and still got `CS0407 ` error. What version of VS exactly? I got 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Comment: 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.

Comment: @IvanStoev that is (for me) also a way to remove the compiler error and what I expected the C# compiler to do for me implicitly

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga Sounds logical to me:) Looks like the compiler does not consider the return type when resolving the overloads. Probably [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) can explain that if he gets to this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The error message associated with CS0121 only displays the first two ambiguous matches. The error applies to all signatures of `Sum`. You can prove this yourself by writing an extension class that matches the `Sum` signature and switching the order of the methods within the class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal TestSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, decimal> selector)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public static int TestSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public static int? TestSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int?> selector)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Extensions.TestSum<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, decimal>)' and 
'Extensions.TestSum<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, int>)'
```

The return type of a method is not considered to be part of it's signature. Again you can prove this by writing two methods with the same name that only differ in return type:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public decimal TestReturn(int value) { return 0m; }
    public int TestReturn(int value) { return 0; }
}

CS0111  Type 'TestClass' already defines a member called 'TestReturn' with the same parameter types
```

So when looking for an overload of `Sum` that accepts a `Func` with the correct signature, only parameters are considered, not return types, in this case `IThing`, which causes it to match all overloads of `Sum` and therefore be ambiguous.